# How to return long after Date Subtract?

Tags: c#, datetime, long-integer

```
DateTime dtLastUse = date1.Subtract(date2);     
Long lSubtract = dtLastUse.Ticks;
```

The Result I Get:

My Result return something like this `{ 14433.14:02:30 }`

How to return me only `14434`?

Comment: That code wouldn't compile, because `DateTime.Subtract(DateTime)` returns a `TimeSpan` (I'm assuming both `date1` and `date2` are of type `DateTime`) - and there's no built-in type called `Long`. It's also unclear what you want the result to be - the difference in days? Hours? Minutes? Ticks? Something else? Please provide a [mcve] with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The result of subtracting a date from another date is a `TimeSpan`. This is to prevent exactly the kind of confusion you're having. If you want to get the total number of days, use `TotalDays`. You can round that value the way you want (e.g. use `Math.Floor` if you want the number of *complete* days) and cast to `int` to get an integer value.

Just because `Ticks` has the same data type you want doesn't mean it's what you want. It essentially gives you the full time resolution possible of the data in the `TimeSpan` (which happens to be tenths of microseconds).

Comment: Tenths of *microseconds* - a tick is 100ns.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, my bad :) Weirdly, the example in `TimeSpan.Ticks` shows Ticks to be just ten times the number of total milliseconds (it says correctly that it's 100ns in the remakrs section).

Comment: In other words `long lSubtract = Convert.ToInt64(date1.Subtract(date2).TotalMilliseconds) / 10;`

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, I just noticed there's a _decimal point_ in the `TotalMilliseconds`. My bad again :)

Comment: @DrGriff Actually, `/ 10000`. But the main point is exactly that you shouldn't bother with that. That's why `TimeSpan` is a struct with helper methods and not just `long` in the first place.

Comment: @Luaan - totally agree!